# ASP.NET app users registration in orchard database

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

My orchard database with 80 tables are integrated to my existing ASP.NET applications database(having 5 tables).After integrating orchard to my database totally 85 tables are there in my orchard database. Now I want the users in ASP app database also should be login in through my orchard app.  can any one suggest how its possible. Its my client requirement.

Comment: How -1 was happened?

Comment: I can't speak for the person who downvoted you but this is a fairly broad question and without at least an example of the data in your existing user table(s) the most specific answer that anyone can give you is probably going to be that you should migrate your user data to the Orchard_Users table. If you run into a specific problem doing that (e.g. different password hashing format) that you don't know how to work around, you could put that in a question with sufficient details and relevant code snippets.

Comment: Okay tahnk you. Is there any way to connect my "aspnet_users" table to "orchard_users" table. My requirement is like SSO(Single Sign On).

Comment: My existing table is "aspnet_users" and orchard table is "orchard_users".

Comment: The cleanest way would be to use the import/export-Module in orchard.
Create a user in orchard and export it to get a valid template. Then export your existing users into this xml template and import them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to solve this issue:

1. If you want to use Orchard.Users module as is, you must migrate your data to Orchard_Users table.
2. If you want to use ASP.Net App users table as is, you must suppress the default implementation of "IMembershipService" to do the CRUD operation on the app users table (you can find the default implantation of "IMembershipService" within Orchard.Users module).